# Group Policy Issue

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012-r2, gpo

I'm hoping you can help. For a bit of background one of our Domain Controllers is Server 2008 R2 and the other is 2012 R2, the 2012 R2 contains the more recent ADMX files. The primary DC is the 2008 version and we plan on upgrading this soon.

I have a Default Domain Policy that contains a basic logon script (.bat) that maps drives and adds documents to users desktops. This policy is Enforced and Link Enabled and pushes to all OU's.

I have an additional Policy setup within an OU that is linked to our domain, this includes a Powershell script that runs at logon. This was created on the secondary DC (2012) as it uses the "Start Screen Layout" feature within Start Menu and Taskbar - the primary DC (2008) doesn't have this features available.

For some reason the Default Domain Policy isn't running, the second policy however is successfully running. Is there any reason this might be happening? I've had a mess with the enforcement options for the second policy but I can't fathom out why it's not running both.

It's definately something to do with the Powershell commands I have running in the second policy, if I remove these the default policy login scripts run fine.

**Some More Info**

To explain, there's 3 scripts in total (all of which sit in the Policy location within sysvol). The first ps1 file copies a shortcut for devices and printers from a network location that all users have access to and pastes it into %appdata% for all users. Part of this script uses the startlayout.xml to reference this location which then add the shortcut to the users start menu.

`Copy-Item -Path "\\Server\Share\*.lnk" -Destination "$env:APPDATA\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"`

The next command removes a load of the bloatware that Win 10 installs to a users profile, I won't post all of the apps in the script but a few so you get the gist:

`$AppList = @(
    "*Microsoft.3dbuilder*"
    "*AdobeSystemsIncorporated.AdobePhotoshopExpress*"
    "*Microsoft.WindowsAlarms*"
    "*Microsoft.Asphalt8Airborne*"
)
foreach ($App in $AppList) {
    Get-AppxPackage -Name $App | Remove-AppxPackage -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}`

The script that is added as the actual logon script references the location the two scripts above sit in and run them:

`Get-ChildItem \\domain\SysVol\domain\Policies\'{Policy Number}'\User\Scripts\Logon | ForEach-Object {
  & $_.FullName
}`

Hope this helps, whether or not there's isn't an exit command maybe I'm not sure as I'm not too savy with Powershell scripting.

**Further Update**

Hi All, another update. I've made all my drive mappings and document copies through Group Policy now which eliminates the first policy therefore there is only one logon script that should run now which is to remove the Bloatware. I've decided to try and call it from a .bat file using the following command:
`PowerShell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -WindowStyle Hidden -File "\\domainm\SysVol\domain\Policies\{Policy Number}\User\Scripts\Logon\BloatwareRemoval.ps1"'-Wait}"` 
Again this will only run after a user logs on for the second time. Is there something glaringly obvious I'm missing here?Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the second policy is enforced, then you will have to check the group policy inheritance to make sure things are applied in the order you expect. Secondly, I feel like newer clients have issues running batch files at logon. If your primary client base is Windows 10, the batch files may fail anyway.

Comment: Hi @AdminOfThings If I look at the inheritance it has the detault domain policy as the first followed by the second policy (including the powershell scripts), this is setup how I assume it to run. It's definately something to do with the Powershell commands I have running in the second policy, if I remove these the default policy login scripts run fine. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for us that is running in the second policy script?

Comment: @AdminOfThings I've added some more info to my original question which will hopefully help. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is difficult to troubleshoot this issue here. I'd start with a methodical way of verifying things. I'd test is putting all of those group policies on a machine as local policies so that you can have complete control without impacting the environment. If you do that, then you can change the files to log what is happening. If that yields nothing significant, I would test using group policy preferences for all the scripts and converting the batch to PowerShell.

Comment: You can also do something wacky like have the second policy scripts do the mapping the default domain policy is doing. I know that is a hack job, but it depends on how desperate you are.

Comment: I know that all the policies run successfully but for some reason the Powershell script prevents the logon batch file from running. If I remove the Powershell script then it runs with no problems.

Comment: The policies can run successfully without the scripts running successfully. You need to add logging to the scripts themselves to see where problems are occurring.

Comment: OK, do you happen to know how to do that? For batch and Powershell.

Comment: There isn't really a prescriptive way to answer that. I would verify that each script command runs successfully by following it with a check of the setting it should have changed. You can log that data to a file in powershell using `out-file -path "filepath" -append`. It may be helpful to add a timestamp to each line of the log file, which can be done with the `get-date` cmdlet. You could also use try-catch blocks to see if errors are thrown and write those to the log file as well.

Comment: To update, I've now got the Devices and Printers Shortcut creating through Group Policy which is much better. The startlayout.xml references it and adds it to the start menu which means that I can cancel out two of those scripts and leave only the bloatware removal script. I've just re added that to this policies logon script and the logon bat file runs (adds the docs to the desktop and maps the drives) but the bloatware removal doesn't run. I think I've found the culprit then I just don't know how to get that to run now. Thanks